# jQuery click button how many times?

Tags: jquery, click

I have jTScroller plugin for jQuery and when user for example enter number on remote 54 variable idx holds then value 54. In one 7 items per scroll. So i divide 54 with 7 to get 7.714 and then round number so that i know number of scrolls needs to be clicked. Now my variable result holds rounded value witch is 8. And then looping 8clicks on class name jTscrollerNextButton. My problem is when executing code it clicks only one time so it screools from 1 to 2. It needs to click 8times on class jTscrollerNextButton and scroll 8 times. I have tryed to put .delay(100) but not working.

How can i click 8 times using this code? Do i need delay? Thanks.

```
// scroll down or up
result = Math.round(idx / 7);

for (var i = 1; i < result; i++) {
    $('.jTscrollerNextButton').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

works fine with harcoded 8:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZHx2/

```
var counter = 0;

$('.jTscrollerNextButton').click(function () {
counter++;

$('body').append('<div>' + counter + '</div>');
});

for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
$('.jTscrollerNextButton').click();
}
```